# PyOpenCl benchmark questions

Tags: python, benchmarking, opencl

I was a little modified the standard code from https://github.com/inducer/pyopencl/blob/master/examples/benchmark-all.py

Replaced by numbers, the variable zz

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy
import numpy.linalg as la
import datetime
from time import time
zz=100
a = numpy.random.rand(zz).astype(numpy.float32)
b = numpy.random.rand(zz).astype(numpy.float32)
c_result = numpy.empty_like(a)

# Speed in normal CPU usage
time1 = time()
for i in range(zz):
        for j in range(zz):
                c_result[i] = a[i] + b[i]
                c_result[i] = c_result[i] * (a[i] + b[i])
                c_result[i] = c_result[i] * (a[i] / 2)
time2 = time()
print("Execution time of test without OpenCL: ", time2 - time1, "s")


for platform in cl.get_platforms():
    for device in platform.get_devices():
        print("===============================================================")
        print("Platform name:", platform.name)
        print("Platform profile:", platform.profile)
        print("Platform vendor:", platform.vendor)
        print("Platform version:", platform.version)
        print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Device name:", device.name)
        print("Device type:", cl.device_type.to_string(device.type))
        print("Device memory: ", device.global_mem_size//1024//1024, 'MB')
        print("Device max clock speed:", device.max_clock_frequency, 'MHz')
        print("Device compute units:", device.max_compute_units)

        # Simnple speed test
        ctx = cl.Context([device])
        queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx, 
                properties=cl.command_queue_properties.PROFILING_ENABLE)

        mf = cl.mem_flags
        a_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a)
        b_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=b)
        dest_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, b.nbytes)

        prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
            __kernel void sum(__global const float *a,
            __global const float *b, __global float *c)
            {
                        int loop;
                        int gid = get_global_id(0);
                        for(loop=0; loop<%s;loop++)
                        {
                                c[gid] = a[gid] + b[gid];
                                c[gid] = c[gid] * (a[gid] + b[gid]);
                                c[gid] = c[gid] * (a[gid] / 2);
                        }
                }
                """ % (zz)).build()

        exec_evt = prg.sum(queue, a.shape, None, a_buf, b_buf, dest_buf)
        exec_evt.wait()
        elapsed = 1e-9*(exec_evt.profile.end - exec_evt.profile.start)

        print("Execution time of test: %g s" % elapsed)

        c = numpy.empty_like(a)
        cl.enqueue_read_buffer(queue, dest_buf, c).wait()
        error = 0
        for i in range(zz):
                if c[i] != c_result[i]:
                        error = 1
        if error:
                print("Results doesn't match!!")
        else:
                print("Results OK")
```

If zz=100 i have:

```
('Execution time of test without OpenCL: ', 0.10500001907348633, 's')
===============================================================
('Platform name:', 'AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing')
('Platform profile:', 'FULL_PROFILE')
('Platform vendor:', 'Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.')
('Platform version:', 'OpenCL 1.1 AMD-APP-SDK-v2.5 (684.213)')
---------------------------------------------------------------
('Device name:', 'Cypress\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
('Device type:', 'GPU')
('Device memory: ', 800, 'MB')
('Device max clock speed:', 850, 'MHz')
('Device compute units:', 20)
Execution time of test: 0.00168922 s
Results OK
===============================================================
('Platform name:', 'AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing')
('Platform profile:', 'FULL_PROFILE')
('Platform vendor:', 'Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.')
('Platform version:', 'OpenCL 1.1 AMD-APP-SDK-v2.5 (684.213)')
---------------------------------------------------------------
('Device name:', 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         750  @ 2.67GHz\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
('Device type:', 'CPU')
('Device memory: ', 8183L, 'MB')
('Device max clock speed:', 3000, 'MHz')
('Device compute units:', 4)
Execution time of test: 4.369e-05 s
Results OK
```

We have 3 time:

```
normal  ('Execution time of test without OpenCL: ', 0.10500001907348633, 's')
pyopencl radeon 5870: Execution time of test: 0.00168922 s
pyopencl i5 CPU 750: Execution time of test: 4.369e-05 s
```

First questions pack: what is pyopencl i5 CPU 750? why he faster "normal"('Execution time of test without OpenCL) in 250 times? and why he faster "pyopencl radeon 5870" in ~38 times?

If zz=1000 we have:

```
normal  ('Execution time of test without OpenCL: ', 9.05299997329712, 's')
pyopencl radeon 5870:Execution time of test: 0.0104431 s
pyopencl i5 CPU 750: Execution time of test: 0.00238112 s
```

i5*5=radeon5870

i5*3800=normal

If zz=10000

```
normal its to long... comment code...
redeon58700, Execution time of test: 0.085571 s
i5, Execution time of test: 0.261854 s
```

Here we see how to win video card.

Still very interesting to compare the sequence of times results.
normal_stage1*90=normal_stage2 normal_stage2*~95=normal_stage3(based on experience)

i5_stage1*52=i5_stage2 i5_stage2*109=i5_stage3

radeon5870_stage1*6=radeon_stage2 radeon_stage2*8=radeon_stage3

Сan somebody explain why the results opencl growth has not been a linear?

Comment: Please, post some graphs or tables, which summarzie your performance measurements: it's much easier to analyze them that wat.

Comment: This question gave me some needed detail for creating context in PyOpenCL.  BTW, between doing some Mandelbrot calcs using Numpy with 16 threads on an 8 core machine and doing them in OpenCL on a ENGTX460 I saw a 250x speedup using OpenCL.

Comment: Another interesting tidbit.  I did the same test except the target for OpenCL was an AMD 8 Core 3.1GHz processor.  I saw nearly the same speedup as on the ENGTX460.  I had to install the SDK from AMD to use the processor as an OpenCL target.  This SDK also makes ATI cards available as targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the growth is unlikely to be linear, since algorithm complexity is O(zz^2).

To draw conclusions about 'linearity' you should have more than 3 points (and error bar is also quite useful when doing such analysis), because for GPU 100 threads is by far not enough to fully utilize it computational power (as your experiment shows, GPU starts beating CPU only with 10k or more threads -- it's quite normal situation).

250-times speed-up on CPU only is also not all that improbable, since python is interperted language, so not very fast by itself, and OpenCL actively uses SIMD instructions of the CPU, which also gives quite good speed boost, even when compared to C+OpenMP.